# Что значит "expanded" и "collapsed" tree node?

Tags: java

Выполняю учебное задание по Java, цель состоит в написании класса по заданному интерфейсу. Класс должен реализовать узел дерева (для каждого узла есть 1 родитель и коллекция детей). Среди прочего, есть в интерфейсе два метода, которые описаны следующим образом:

```
/**
 * Returns the "expanded" state of this <code>TreeNode</code>.<br/>
 * By default (unless {@link #setExpanded(boolean)} is called)
 *  "expanded" is false (i.e. the node is "collapsed").
 */
boolean isExpanded();
/**
 * Sets the "expanded" state to this <code>TreeNode</code> and to all its children, recursively
 * @param expanded true - to expand this tree branch, false - to collapse this tree branch.
 */
void setExpanded(boolean expanded);
```

Не очень понятно в чём состоит скрытый смысл слова "expanded". Если я правильно понял, можно реализовать эти два метода просто засунув в описание узла поле `boolean expanded = false`, методом `isExpanded()` возвращать эту переменную, а в методе `setExpanded()` установить значение этой переменной в `true/false` для данного узла, всех его детей, его детей детей и т.д. для всех узлов, для которых данный узел является корневым. Или кроме этого нужно проводить ещё какие-то операции с узлом? Просто слегка напрягает фраза

> true - to expand this tree branch, false - to collapse this tree branch

Возникает ощущение, будто я должен что-то делать с отходящими от данного узла ветками.

Comment: А потомков-то зачем сворачивать/разворачивать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isExpanded()` возвращает `true` когда узел раскрыт, если не раскрыт возвращает `false`;

`setExpanded()` это сеттер для переменной `expanded`.

Comment: ok. Но ведь эта фигня используется только для графического интерфейса -- во всяких файловых менеджерах и т.д.? Просто у меня то только структура-дерево дана, для хранения данных...

Comment: @hunter, ну наверно имеется ввиду что бы на логическом уровне это было.

Comment: @hunter, может быть потом, когда вы напишете библиотеку классов, это(_логику_) Вы сможете легко прикрутить к UI.